# Using Firebase as backend

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

For the past few days, I've been trying to understand what exactly is Firebase. I am in need of some more 'beginner-friendly' answers on the subject. My intention is to create a backend for my Android project. For my previous project , I used a GoDaddy host , PHP, MySQL and it did work just fine.

I am in need of stuff like these :

1. Storing string data. Like user email , password , profile picture path , number of friends etc.. (in a single row)
2. Uploading and downloading files. Video , audio
3. Creating a real time chat messaging system inside the app.

I am currently reading Firebase guides on user authentication. For example there is a method for signing a new user with email and password , but what if I want to store more than just email and password? Is Firebase fully customizable? Is it easy to use , or is it designed for professional developers only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase is fully customisable yes.

If you want to store more than an email,password etc, you can do so my creating a well structured JSON first. You can then try and map this to firebase db.

Firebase is a good and stable backend as a service platform and it is used by plenty of professional apps. It is fairly easy to use. Follow their youtube channel for tutorials. They have very good tutorials and explanations about how things work. I am in the exact same boat as you, learning firebase.

You may also want to look at alternatives like pubnub and pusher for the requirement of yours. They work in a similar way.

Hope this clears some of your doubts

Comment: hi Kushan , thanks for answer. Just a side question : If the data is stored in json form and not in a sql table , how do I perform a select query when I need some data ? for example , I don't want the whole user list data , I just need the users which have email adresses starting with the letter 'a'?

Comment: I hope you did understand me , poor english

Comment: you would use a reference to the root object. Then take a child reference say user1. Now under this user1 node you would have another child called password whose value you would retreive using getValue()

Comment: select queries work using listeners in firebase. Really, go look at the videos on their channel.i have learnt everything from the videos :)

Comment: PubNub and Firebase work more as complementary technologies than replacing one for the other. Firebase's specialty is client/server/client data sync in realtime and PubNub is focused on highly scalable message delivery (Data Stream Network). See this example on using both together: https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2016-09-01-diy-virtual-white-board-using-google-and-firebase/